# I got an error for the expression containing parenthesis

Tags: python, parentheses

```
print((4 + 2) / (4 % 2))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print((4 + 2) / (4 % 2))
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: a number cannot be divided by zero. here 4%2 results 0. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to evaluate `(4 + 2) / (4 % 2)`.  Well `(4 + 2)` is `6`, and `(4 % 2)` is `0`.  So you're evaluating `6 / 0` which produces a division-by-zero error.